# Wordpress Redirect Loop on a featured post permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a site and I have a custom post type and that post type is featured to the home page. When you click read more you get "this webpage has a redirect loop" This only happens on this post. Why is this happening?

You can see it here. http://taabc.org/

If you go down to Alumni Spotlight and click read more. That is where I get the error.

Please help!

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'alumni spotlight',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<div class="alumni-spotlight-bg">

<div id="container" class="alumni-spotlight">


<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<h2>Alumni Spotlight</h2>
<div class="alumni-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div class="alumni-spotlight-video"><?php the_field( 'youtube_video' ); ?></div>
<p><?php the_field( 'excerpt' ); ?></p>
<a class="alumni-spotlight-btn" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/core/images/buttons/read-more-btn.png" /></a>


<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>There are no posts or pages here.</p>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>


</div><!-- End alumni-spotlight --->
```

Comment: Go to Settings > Permalinks in the admin and save your permalinks.  It will flush the rewrite rules.  It might work. If that doesn't work post your custom post type code as well.

Comment: I just added the code for that section.